# Diagram drawing application

Tags: diagrams, drawing

I need to draw a complex value network and the Visio isn't fitting my needs.

Does someone know the drawing program used to draw the diagrams in the Android Design website? That would fit my needs.

Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yONd5.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html) - its a FOSS tool meant for prototyping - which is available either as a standalone software for Windows, Linux and OS X, or as a firefox extension

[image]

Comment: Are you sure Pencil was used? It does not look the same at all.

Comment: @Synetech Ohh, i thought you just wanted something that had the *capabilities* to draw like what you found in the Android SDK - and Visio just wasn't cutting it.

Comment: That seems to be what the second sentence is asking, but the first one is asking about the specific program used to make the specified diagram. He seems to want that program in particular, but may be satisfied with other options (in which case it would be closed as a duplicate—or rather [n-tuplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+diagram+software)—qustion).

Comment: I'm looking for the program used in Android SDK.

Comment: @Ian Boyd I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: So instead some mean-spirited person comes along and closes the question. What a dick.